# connection between two tables in firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

in firebase I have two tables: itinerary with id, title, hour, minutes, seconds, description, level of difficulty and image while in review I have title, image and rating now I should insert the itinerary id, generated with getNewKey, in review so that one itinerary has several reviews. The created method is:

```
public void addReview() {
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    referenceDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    String titleReview = insertReviews_fragment.getTitleReview();
    String descriptionReview = insertReviews_fragment.getDescriptionReview();
    String voteItinerary = insertReviews_fragment.getVoteReview();
    
    //String ItineraryId = String.valueOf(explore_fragment.getId());

     String itineraryId = referenceDb.child("Itinerary").push().getKey();


     ReviewDao reviewDao = new ReviewDao();
    String reviewId = reviewDao.getNewKey();

     if (images != null) {
        StorageReference reviewRef = storageReference.child("review_image/").child(reviewId + ".jpg");
        reviewRef.putFile(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(images))).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    reviewRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                            String uid = auth.getUid();
                            String email = firebaseUser.getEmail();

                            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("titleReview", titleReview);
                            map.put("image", uri.toString());
                            map.put("email", email);
                            map.put("voteReview", voteItinerary);
                            map.put("descriptionReview", descriptionReview);
                            map.put("userId", uid);
                            map.put("reviewId", reviewId);
                            map.put("ItineraryId", itineraryId);

                            referenceDb.child("Reviews").child(reviewId).setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        //APRO SCHERMATA List Review
                                        Toast.makeText(insertReviews_fragment.getActivity(), "Operation successful, thanks for your feedback", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        openListReviewsFragment();

                                    } else {

                                        //ERRORE
                                        Toast.makeText(insertReviews_fragment.getActivity(), "Operation failed. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(insertReviews_fragment.getActivity(), task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(insertReviews_fragment.getActivity(), "Please add image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }

public void getAllItinerary(){
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference referenceDb = database.getReference("Itinerary");

        itineraryList = new ArrayList<>();

        Itinerary iter = new Itinerary();
        itineraryList.clear();

        referenceDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> dataSnapsho1 = snapshot.getChildren();

                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapsho1) {

                    if(ds.child("titleItinerary").getValue() != null){
                        Itinerary iter = new Itinerary(
                                (String) ds.child("itineraryId").getValue(),
                                (String) ds.child("titleItinerary").getValue(),
                                (String) ds.child("descriptionItinerary").getValue(),
                                (String) ds.child("difficultyLevel").getValue(),
                                (String) ds.child("hours").getValue(),
                                (String) ds.child("minutes").getValue(),
                                (String) ds.child("seconds").getValue(),
                                String.valueOf(ds.child("image").getValue()));
                        iter.setEmail((String)ds.child("email").getValue());
                        itineraryList.add(iter);
                    }
                }
                adapterListItinerary = new AdapterListItinerary(getActivity(), itineraryList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterListItinerary);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

But this way a new id code is associated with the itineraryId attribute in the reviews table. How can I fix?

Comment: "How can I fix?" is not a clear problem statement. When you step through this code line by line in a debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? What does it do? And what did you expect?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen There are no errors but when I write this " String itineraryId = referenceDb.child("Itinerary").push().getKey();" a new id is created which is associated with a non-existent itinerary instead I already have an itineraries table which contains the itineraries to which an id corresponds...I don't know if I explained myself well :(

Comment: Every time you call `push()` it generates a new ID. If you want to update an existing node, you'll need to **know** the ID of that node already. For example, if you show the itineraries in the UI, their keys are present in the data snapshot that you get from the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay then I'll explain better I have a recycleview with all the itineraries now when I click on a cardi view on the recycleview I access the screen containing all the details of the itinerary and two buttons one that allows me to enter the review and one that allows me to view all the reviews, and everything up to here is going correctly now the problem is that I want to insert the itinerary id in each review so that each itinerary corresponds to a series of reviews and not reviews of other itineraries

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen now if I delete the push I don't get any itinerary id there is the itineraryId field disappears

Comment: I load the itineraries with the method indicated in the main post, i.e. "getAllItinerary"

Comment: So inside `getAllItinerary()` you will need to call `ds.getKey()` and track that value, just as you show the child properties in the UI. Then when the user clicks on an item to delete, you can look up that key and use it to delete the correct node.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but I don't have to delete. In reality, I want to make sure that when I view the reviews of an itinerary, the reviews of other itineraries do not appear... I wanted to do this by inserting the itinerary id in the review that is created, i.e. when the user enters the review

Comment: Sorry, I might have mixed up with a different question about deletion. But you'll still need to track/pass the itinerary ID from the moment you load it from the database to the place where you need it to write to the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Who should I have access to in the review insert that I did with the hashMap... and what do I write to make it work?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how to help further than what I've done already: if you want to associate the new review with an existing `itineraryId`, you will have to pass that itinerary ID from wherever you load it in your UI already. There's no way for us to say what that means based on the code you shared.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay yes this i want to do but in the hash map i don't know how to insert it...now with the getallItinerary method written in the comment below I have all the itineraries with the codes